# Trying to get a multi colored background

Tags: html, css

I am making a personal bio site, and I want different color backgrounds for the header, body, and footer. I found this website, http://www.chimengxi.com/ and that is kinda what I am going for. In the end, I hope to get my header to be horizontal, instead of stacked. Some 3 toned color scheme would be awesome if its doable.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Personal Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">School</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">Contact Information</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h1><a href="index.php">Terrence Horgan <br> Information Science Major </a></h1>
        <h2><u>My Personal  Website...About ME!</u></h2>
        <p id="summary">Here is a little about myself....</p>
        <p>My name is Terrence Horan, I love in Montour Falls, NY, not to far from Ithaca, NY. I attend Cornell University and am majoring in Information Science, and hopefully will get a minor in Computer Science. I love anything that involves technology,however if you would like to read more, dont be shy! Come in a browse my website!</p>
        <div class="footer">Call me (607-425-0760)<address>Email Me <a href="mailto:tmh233@cornell.edu">tmh233@cornell.edu</a>.<br></address>
            </a>Copyright @ 2014 Terrence Horgan</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:orange;
    height:100%
}
ul.navbar {
    background-color:orange;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:175%
}
.navbar ul {
    height:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block
}
.navbar li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}
h1 {
    position:relative;
    bottom:85px
}
h1 a:hover, a:active {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#3CF;
    text-decoration:none
}
h1 a:visited, a:link {
    color:#F36;
    text-decoration:none
}
p {
    width:30%;
    font-size:120%
}
#summary {
    font-size:135%;
    font-weight:700
}
.footer {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative
}
```

Comment: You can freely choose the colours you want to use for your elements... no limits.

Comment: If I start making an answer for this I'll end up writing you a whole freaking website.

Comment: @Deryck Seems like that's what the OP expects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your navbar in a div. Style the div background-color however you want.
2. Wrap the content below the navbar and above the footer in another div. Style accordingly.
3. Set background-color of footer to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of changing the colors. I made them quite noticeable by coloring them green and yellow and adding a few simple CSS styles to make them fit accordingly (floats, text-aligns). Look at the code below, and please note I pasted your CSS at the top. All you need to do is paste the code between the  tags into your CSS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    body {
    height:100%
        }

ul.navbar {
    background-color:green;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:175%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar ul {
    height:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;

}
.navbar li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
h1 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
            text-align: left;
}
h1 a:hover, a:active {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#3CF;
    text-decoration:none
}
h1 a:visited, a:link {
    color:#F36;
    text-decoration:none
}
p {
    width:30%;
    font-size:120%
}
#summary {
    font-size:135%;
    font-weight:700
}
.footer {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}</style>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Personal Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <h1><a href="index.php">Terrence Horgan <br> Information Science Major </a></h1>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">School</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">Contact Information</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h2><u>My Personal  Website...About ME!</u></h2>
        <p id="summary">Here is a little about myself....</p>
        <p>My name is Terrence Horan, I love in Montour Falls, NY, not to far from Ithaca, NY. I attend Cornell University and am majoring in Information Science, and hopefully will get a minor in Computer Science. I love anything that involves technology,however if you would like to read more, dont be shy! Come in a browse my website!</p>
        <div class="footer">Call me (607-425-0760)<address>Email Me <a href="mailto:tmh233@cornell.edu">tmh233@cornell.edu</a>.<br></address>
            </a>Copyright @ 2014 Terrence Horgan</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried that, tho see how the footer is not directly at the bottom? and the background for the nav bar does not go all the way to the top? I knew i needed to wrap them in divs and style them, just didnt know how to get it all the way up and down.

Comment: Here is a website you can use to find out more about sticky footers: [link](http://www.adhamdannaway.com/blog/web-design/css-sticky-footer-sticks-your-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page).All you need to add to your CSS is: `body {
height:100%;
margin: 0px;
        }
        
.navbar {
    margin:-14px 0 -14px 0;
}`